# Importing a part of a project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, ffmpeg

On Eclipse, I imported FFmpeg as a project to reduce a selected video sizes for my android application. But my .apk size went up from 2MB to 24MB.

This project includes a lot of extra properties for video editing. However I use only one single command line to reduce my video resolution. The code I added:

```
LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
                    try {
                        String workFolder = getApplicationContext()
                                .getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();

                        String[] complexCommand = {
                                "ffmpeg",
                                "-y",
                                "-i",
                                "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20150224_125355.mp4",
                                "-strict", "experimental", "-s", "160x120",
                                "-r", "25", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b", "150k",
                                "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050",
                                "/storage/emulated/0/TempFolder/out.mp4" };
                        vk.run(complexCommand, workFolder,
                                getApplicationContext());

                        Log.i("test", "ffmpeg4android finished successfully");
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("test", "vk run exception.", e);
                    }
```

To sum up, is there a way to import a portion of a project (as a module maybe) ? or do I have to find another method to reduce my video size ?

Comment: "is there a way to import a portion of a project (as a module maybe) ?" -- that would be a fine question for the author of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not really importing a project – you're using a binary called `ffmpeg`, which is an executable file that contains all of the third-party libraries statically compiled into one package. You cannot make this file any smaller. You can only compile it with fewer libraries enabled.

Your ffmpeg binary, when you run it without any arguments, shows various `--enable` options that were set before compilation. For example, my ffmpeg includes almost everything there is:

```
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.6 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfaac --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-openssl --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libcaca --enable-libsoxr --enable-libquvi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 ' --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
```

For example, if you have `--enable-libfaac` your ffmpeg includes an FAAC audio encoder which is not strictly necessary and increases the binary file size. You're using whatever the binary compiled from [github.com/faywong/ffmpeg4android](https://github.com/faywong/ffmpeg4android) does – so you need to change the way ffmpeg4android builds the ffmpeg binary to include less.

The absolute minimum build of ffmpeg that is actually useful would include `libx264` only, if you plan on encoding H.264 video with AAC audio. To do that, you'd have to configure ffmpeg with `--enable-libx264`. But in your question, your command has `mpeg4` as codec, which is an MPEG-4 Visual encoder built into ffmpeg, so you theoretically can just stick with this. Keep in mind that MPEG-4 Visual is not as efficient as H.264 and will yield larger files for the same quality—or lower quality at the same bitrate.

But it depends on how yours was built. If you really have nothing enabled apart from maybe libx264 and your build is that large, there's not much you can do about it if you want to keep ffmpeg. A standalone video encoder like x264 may be smaller, but has limited capabilities in terms of what formats/codecs it can read and write to.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has the option to Import proyects, files, src, packages to a existing proyect or to a new one.
You can import files, right click on Proyect > Import >  General > Archive File.
Or File System if is a src or package. Maybe that can help you.